# Tikz positioning above circle exact alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can the balls `b1` and `b2` be aligned exactly above each other? Also, `above=1cm of b1.center, anchor=center` and all kinds of combinations with `north` - `south`, `north east` - `south west` does not yield the desired result.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{ball/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=.1cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, ball}]{
        \node (b1) {b1}; &
        \node (b2) [above=.1cm of b1] {b2}; \\
    };
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you might want to explain in more detail what your end goals is here. To me it does not seem the `\matrix` is the right tool to use here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code with the `matrix` is not correct because your nodes are on same row, they are separated by `&` and there is only one `\\` in your matrix.

If you want to use a matrix, I propose following code which loads `matrix` library and uses a `matrix of nodes` to simplify syntax.

But I think second solution is better, just use `above=0pt of ...` and you'll get two nodes one above the other.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}
\tikzset{ball/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=.1cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, ball}, row sep=0pt]{
        b2\\
        b1\\
    };

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ball] (b1) {b1};
\node[ball, above=0pt of b1] (b2) {b2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to finally make a grid of balls that is why I used matrix in the first place. I just reduced it to the essential part for the MWE.